# Redirecting a domain with htaccess with a few specific 301s

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to do something like this to redirect old traffic to the new site with a 301.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, I will need to manually map some pages to their new equivalent pages like

```
Redirect 301 /about http://new-example.com/about-us
```

Is it possible to do both?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `Rewrite`, then use it only. I don't recommend use both `mod-alias` and `mod-rewrite`. You can use rewrite to map to individual pages too. Also the order matters. The `catchall` rule should be the last one. This would provide cleaner code IMO.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ http://new-example.com/about-us [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```